# PHP Elasticsearch Query

Tags: php, html, elasticsearch

I am trying to build a small web application to demo elasticsearch's capabilities, but I am running into an issue with my query. My goal is to search a string of keywords over all indexes and fields.  What I currently have seems to only search `AttachmentBody`, as when I search for `BugID xyz` or `AttachmentTitle xyz` nothing is displayed.  I would greatly appreciate any help you may have to offer!

```
<?php

require_once 'es/esconnect.php';

if (isset($_GET['q'])){
    $q = $_GET['q'];
    $query = $Client->search([
        'body' =>[
            'query' =>[
                'bool' =>[
                    'should' =>[
                        'match' => ['BugID' => $q],
                        'match' => ['AttachmentTitle' => $q],
                        'match' => ['AttachmentBody' => $q]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    if($query['hits']['total'] >=1){
        $results = $query['hits']['hits'];
    }
}

?>
```

---

BugID: CSCzo56214

AttachmentTitle: 15624_note_21844

AttachmentBody: this is a note

---

BugID: CSCzo56214

AttachmentTitle: 15624_description_21846

AttachmentBody: this is a description

---

Working query:

```
    'body' =>[
        'query' =>[
            'bool' =>[
                'should' => array(
        array('match' => array('BugID' => $q)),
        array('match' => array('AttachmentTitle' => $q)),
        array('match' => array('AttachmentBody' => $q))
    )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider adding a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can better help you. So if you can share a sample document that should match as well as what `$q` would be, it'll be easier for people to help.

Comment: Can you maybe show a sample document with sample values?

Comment: The inner-most array only consists of one element (key: `match`, value: `['AttachmentBody' => $q]`), because each consecutive mention of the same key, overwrites the previous. Without knowing elasticsearch, my best guess is that you want something like: `'match' => ['BugID' => $q, 'AttachmentTitle' => $q, 'AttachmentBody' => $q]`.

Comment: Hi Val, sure.  I added it to the initial post.  Thanks for the help!


Yoshi, I thought that would be the problem too but it throws an exception:

[match] query parsed in simplified form, with direct field name, but included more options than just the field name, possibly use its 'options' form, with 'query' element?"

Comment: As I said, unfortunately I don't have any experience with elasticsearch. But I'm pretty sure, that you simply have to find the correct query-structure (as elasticsearch requires it).

Comment: Hey, @Yoshi thanks for the help!  In case you are interested, I was able to get this to work:

 sorry, I cant get it to work in this comment... will post in my question.

Comment: If you have an answer, don't be afraid to post it as such, you can even accept it. That's not a problem here on SO.

Comment: Ok, cool.  I did not know that was possible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functioning query:

```
'body' => [
    'query' => [
        'bool' => [
            'should' => [
                ['match' => ['BugID'           => $q]],
                ['match' => ['AttachmentTitle' => $q]],
                ['match' => ['AttachmentBody'  => $q]]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```